# Running a glmer to find if the difference between two proportions is significant

Tags: lme4-nlme, chi-squared-test, proportion, intercept

I'm running a study wherein participants classify some faces they see. And I aim to examine if the probability for accurate categorization for a face is larger than a baseline probability I've got for each face from prior research. The faces vary by gender which will be a covariate.

Normally, I'd use a chi-squared test to test if the difference between two proportions is significantly greater than zero but I want to include random effects for each face that is classified. Can I run a glmer with this? Something like this:

```r
model <- glmer(proportionDifference ~ targetGender + (1| target), 
               family = binomial)
```

And then assess intercept significance to infer if the proportions were significantly different from one another?

Comment: Classifying faces into which/how many categories?

Comment: They classify faces into 7 categories but we are only interested in 2

Comment: And each participant classifies many faces?

Comment: Yes they do - each participant classifies many faces but not all faces in the set